# How to tell if a line in /etc/passwd is a malacious user

Tags: 14.04, security, users

When I go to /etc/passwd, how do I know if a user shouldn't be there? There are a lot of random users with weird names like "games" "sys" etc. i know id under 1000 is hidden but about 70% users are like that...

Comment: You use your favourite online search engine and research that user name... - no, seriously. If this is a general question, that was the general answer. Otherwise please make your question more specific by listing the user names you are unsure about or pasting your `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Is there a general list of allowed system users?

Comment: You could compare it to a list of users on a fresh clean install of Ubuntu, but note that also some legit applications register hidden user accounts. It would not be a definitive list.

Comment: Ok, so I just search it up, and if it doesn't seem to be a "default" user I'll remove it

Comment: Don't just do that if you're not sure what its purpose is. The application or service it belongs to may stop working.

Comment: Only one I know for sure is malicious is the really obvious "toor"

Comment: Honestly, if you see a chance that your system was compromised in any way, nuke it from orbit and do a fresh clean install. If the attacker (no matter whether any kind of malware or a human hacker) managed to create a user account, they can also have modified other parts of your system that you aren't even aware of to make sure they don't lose control.

Comment: To sum it up, deleting some arbitrary system users will surely not clean your machine from any kind of infection or defend an attack, but it has a high chance of breaking things. Don't do it.

Comment: Also, what makes you think "toor" is malicious?

Comment: Isn't it an alternate root account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, there's no standard way to identify a username as being malicious/non-malicious. There are certain standard users such as `nobody`, `daemon`, and `whoopsie`, so you can safely exclude those. I'd recommend creating a fresh install in VirtualBox and taking a peak at the `/etc/passwd` or ask a friend who has relatively unaltered system.

The username you brought up in the comments, `toor`, is frequently used to create a root-level user with extra permissions, while leaving a different account for regular use. Judging form your comments, you didn't create that, and we don't know if this machine is second-hand or not.  If it was second-hand, it is quite possible it was created by the previous owner. Otherwise, you might be right in suspecting intrusion into your system.

Fighting off intrusion can be somewhat tricky. Simplest and most effective approach is to backup files and reinstall the OS. Investigating the connections and which files/daemons/cronjobs have been compromised can be time consuming.

Comment: I still recommend a nuke if there are indications for an infection. Related: [How do you explain the necessity of “nuke it from orbit” to management and users?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/24195/66413)

Comment: @ByteCommander agreed, it's one of the best solutions if there's 100% certainty of intrusion.